# UIMenuController меню на анлийском

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Почему меню на английском? В настройках эмулятора везде русский. Как сменить на Русский?

[image: Почему меню на Английском]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224969/localizing-the-cutcopypaste-menu-on-ios

Comment: Спасибо помогли, то что нужно